# Tool for examining database columns to determine their contents

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design

I'm working with an incompletely documented DBMS system, and I am looking for a general purpose software tool that will examine the values in columns and return a description of what's in there.

I guess I'm looking for a cross between `DESCRIBE`, `SELECT DISTINCT col`, `SELECT MIN(COL), MAX(COL)`, and other summary statistics.

Ideally I'd like it to be able to do such things as detect a text column and announce things like "This column is UTF-8 text, 5% NULL, 15% one word, 30% two words, 35% three words, and the rest something else.

Or "This column is a datestamp.  Values lie in the range 2001-02-01 : 2024-01-01. with no NULLs"

Does this tool exist anywhere? Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Data Profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_profiling) tool.

There's an open source product called [Talend Open Profilier](http://www.talend.com/products-data-quality/talend-open-profiler.php) which can be used to profile data. There are also several commercial products available - [Informatica](http://www.informatica.com/Pages/data_profiling_index.aspx), [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895310.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Db Visualizer
http://www.dbvis.com/

You can get a community edition for free.

Comment: I happen to know dbvis fairly well but this is not doing the task as asked. We can write sql that does the task using any sql tool, inlcuding dbvis.